# What is the father dying of in The Road?

Tags: the-road

In Cormac McCarthy's novel (and subsequent film adaptation), the Father/Man is slowly dying throughout the whole story. He eventually degrades to a point where he's coughing up large volumes of blood. He then (arguably) dies from exhaustion and/or some kind of respiratory failure.

**I'm interested in *why*.**

In the movie, there are only a few statements he makes/narrates that hint at the possible cause, but they are (intentionally) vague and leave you guessing.

There seems to be a strong leading theory that the cause of the apocalypse is a major natural disaster, such as the eruption of a supervolcano due to the continuous earthquakes and gradual death of plantlife. Either way (even if you subscribe to the nuclear war theory or some other theory) *if* the supervolcano theory were true, perhaps the cause of his illness is some kind of breathing/pulmonary injury brought about from him breathing in particulate matter from the eruption. But then, if that were the case, you'd figure his son would be affected as well.

**I'm wondering if there's more info in the book that explains what his ailments are? Or something that I missed in the movie?**

Comment: [The script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Road,-The.html) seems to imply that it's lung cancer, a lung infection or possibly something related to ash inhalation such as [silicosis](http://serc.carleton.edu/NAGTWorkshops/health/case_studies/volcanic_ash.html).

Comment: @Gallifreian lol spoiler alert

Comment: Haha, why would you revert the edit?

Comment: Seriously though, it's considered a nice practice on this website to try to conceal or obscure spoilers.

Comment: Thanks @Valorum (+1) - if you can put this into an answer, and no one else can present refuting "evidence" in the coming days, I'll happily give you the green check!

Comment: @smeeb - You have the script and, as an added bonus, I assume you've actually seen the film (which I haven't). Perhaps you might like to write up a self-answer.

Comment: I will, just wanted to offer that to you, since you had already gone to the effort of finding the script and soliciting a pretty good answer-as-a-comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR There is no answer provided in either book or film, so we can only make an educated guess.

In the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Road,-The.html), the Man says several interesting/telling things, such as:

> Every day is a lie. But I am slowly dying. That is not a lie. I am trying to prepare him for the day when I am gone.

There's also scene descriptions such as:

> The MAN just stands in the middle of the lawn COUGHING his guts up in the dark rain - again the phlemy wet cough. He bends over, sweating, listening, knowing it's the sound of fluid on the lungs.

And perhaps, most telling:

> The MAN stops and rests on the trolley and the BOY pulls on a few more feet then stops and looks back as the MAN COUGHS for a long painful moment. He takes the bloodstained surgical mask from his face, his breath foggy in the cold, **he wrings out the blood and saliva, puts his head between his knees and coughs until he can cough no more, gasping for breathe, bloody drool unspooling from his lips into the sand like scarlet twine** while the BOY watches, weeping silently.

[According to the Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/coughing-up-blood/basics/causes/sym-20050934), there is a small laundry list of conditions that cite "*coughing up blood*" as a primary symptom.

Seeing that we are provided with no evidence of the Man having any genetic malformations (cystic fibrosis, etc.), nor having suffered any acute event that would have brought on symptoms rapidly, nor being a smoker of any kind, nor having skin sores or fever, nor having blue lips or fingernails, nor experiencing episodes of dizziness, then the two remaining ailments on the Mayo Clinic's list are:

- [COPD](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/copd/home/ovc-20204882) (chronic obstructive pulmonary disease); and
- Lung cancer

Both seem plausible, although I *feel* like the McCarthy would have tipped the hat toward lung cancer with a reference or two to smoking (as he did numerous times with the missing thumbs and commune references). **So if I had to choose between the two, and not knowing anything about medicine, I might go with COPD.**

Valorum also mentions [silicosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis) which would tie into the supervolcano theory quite nicely, however you'd think other characters (and certainly the Boy) would have similar symptoms. The Man also doesn't appear to have other symptoms of silicosis, such as blue skin/lips, etc.

**Therefore, as my overly-drawn-out and overly-thought-out answer concludes, unless Cormac McCarthy himself comes on these boards and tells me otherwise, or until a qualified medical professional can rule it out, I'm going with COPD.**

Comment: There's lots of references to ash in the script.

Comment: Silicosis is possible if the Father had a pre-existing health condition that caused him to have a respiratory system more susceptible to foreign matter. Fantastic answer, however!

Answer (score 5):

I think he had lung cancer, when they were in the bunker, he smokes a cigarette with great relief. This implies that he may have been a smoker before the apocalypse and that in the terrible conditions without medical attention, he died from a long progression of lung cancer. The leg wound have further deteriorated his immune system.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nicely reasoned answer but could you [edit] in some quotes or clips to support it?

Answer (score 4):

Basically he dies from blood loss following an arrow wound:

In the book:

> In a town inland, the man is shot in the leg with an arrow. He loses blood and, after several days, realizes he will soon die.

[Wikipedia source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road)

In the film:

> As they pass through a ruined town, the man is shot in the leg with an arrow. He kills his ambusher with a flare gun he found on the ship and finds the archer's female companion in the same room. The man thinks the archer and woman were following them, but she says it was the other way around. He leaves her weeping over the body. Weakened, the man and boy abandon their cart and most of their possessions. The man's condition deteriorates and eventually he dies.

[Wikipedia - source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_(2009_film))

Comment: I appreciate the answer @Pat Dobson (+1) however he is dying throughout the whole story. He's having violent coughing fits and spitting up his own blood long before he takes the arrow to the leg. While I think its plausible that the arrow is what finally weakened him to a state where he died from either blood loss, infection or exhaustion, and therefore is what *finally killed* him, he was dying before he was shot, and that's what I'm inquiring about here. Thanks again!

Comment: Like with many things in the book/film, I don't think that the reason for his malise is specified. I think it is left to the reader to speculate, much like the cause of the 'apocalypse' the world is suffering from . . .

Comment: Right, but my question was whether or not there was evidence in the movie or book that strongly suggested or hinted at a particular root cause to his ailments. If you're stating there wasn't any, then please change your answer to reflect that, and if no one disagrees after a few days, I'll happily give you the green check! Thanks again